# sqlite3_step() returns SQLITE_MISUSE in tutorial situation

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 for the first time, and I can't figure out the following error. Here are the relevant lines:

```
//open db; I checked, and sqlite3_open() returns 0 here (SQLITE_OK)
rc = sqlite3_open(filename.c_str(),&db);

//...

//create & prepare query.
string query = "SELECT * FROM MOCK_DATA;"; //I am positive MOCK_DATA exists and is non empty
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
cout<<sqlite3_prepare(db,query.c_str(),0,&stmt,NULL)<<endl; //this prints 0: SQLITE_OK

//here we get the error 
cout<<sqlite3_step(stmt)<<endl; //returns 21: SQLITE_MISUSE
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `sqlite3_prepare()` is the length of the SQL string. Zero means that your SQL is empty. Supply a negative value such as `-1` to make sqlite3 read up to the first NUL character as in a C string.